# Using grep with fread() to filter rows with whitespace containing string

Tags: r, fread

I'm trying to import a huge tsv file (~6.8 GB)  in chunks by using R's fread() with grep to import the rows that contain the matching string in the field and then manipulating the imported datasets in some way. However, the matching string, contains a whitespace in between two contiguous words, to which grep complains about not finding the file/directory of the second word after that white space. I'm wondering how I can use grep in fread() to match rows based on a string that contains a whitespace in it?

Here's my command to import

```
counts_df <- fread(cmd = paste0("grep ", i, " rna_single_cell_read_count.tsv"), sep = '\t', col.names = col_names) %>% as.data.frame()
```

where `i = 'Heart Muscle'`.

The error that I get is:

```
grep: Muscle: No such file or directory
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Cell, value = "cell_") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Comment: The error is very clear: you are passing multiple arguments to grep, the first of which is "Muscle", and grep expects that first argument to be the file. Enclose the full name in quotes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize that field before assembling your grep command.  You can either insert a backslash character before each whitespace character in the search string, or enclose the whole thing in double quotes.